# SQL Return only rows where the value is the same

Tags: oracle, group-by, having

i'm struggling to get rows where the value is the same in SQL.

**Example**

| recnr | test_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |
| 3 | 102 |
| 4 | 103 |
| 5 | 104 |
| 6 | 104 |
| 7 | 104 |
| 8 | 105 |

I want to see all records that has the same test_id number more then once. So from above sample i would like to see:

| recnr | test_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 102 |
| 3 | 102 |
| 5 | 104 |
| 6 | 104 |
| 7 | 104 |

Anyone an idee how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

I did try to use group by and stuf but probably the wrong way.

Comment: which DBMS is this ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that. It is Oracle 19.

Answer (score 1):

We first get the list of `test_id` that are duplicated using `group by` and `having count(1) > 1` then using `inner join` we get the expected data :

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
  select test_id
  from mytable
  group by test_id
  having count(1) > 1
) as s on s.test_id = t.test_id
```

This is a working solution tested on mysql .. [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tiR02W50)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw the demo and it looks ok, but it seems not to be working on my table. I removed the word "as" at the end and the query gives results now but i see all records now. It is Oracle 19 by the way.

Comment: I changed the query and this seems to work:

select t.*
from mn_itemlogs t
inner join (
  select ITLO_ITHD_ID
  from mn_itemlogs
  group by ITLO_ITHD_ID
) s on s.ITLO_ITHD_ID = t.ITLO_ITHD_ID
order by 2;

Thank you SelVazi, you put me on the right track. The solution from Sumant also seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL SERVER, We can use IN operator, Subquery, GroupBy and Having to get your desired result.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable A WHERE A.test_id IN (  SELECT B.test_id FROM MyTable B GROUP BY B.test_id HAVING COUNT(1)>1  );
```

You can use following queries to test it on any online MS SQL SERVER compiler.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  recnr int,
  test_id int
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0001,101);
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0002, 102);
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0003, 102);
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0004,103);
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0005, 104);
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0006, 104);
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0007,104);
INSERT INTO MyTable(recnr,test_id) VALUES (0008, 105);

-- fetch 
SELECT * FROM MyTable A WHERE A.test_id IN (SELECT  B.test_id FROM MyTable B GROUP BY B.test_id HAVING COUNT(1)>1) ;
GO
```

I have added image for reference.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunally this gives the same result as select * from mytable (all records are shown).

Comment: @Moke please check attached image, i am getting desired output.

Comment: Sumant, thank you very much it seems to work now :).